# Homomorphism $f:S_{2009} \rightarrow S_{2009}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, group-homomorphism

Is there a non-trivial homomorphism $f:S_{2009} \rightarrow S_{2009}$ with $(1,2)$ in the kernel?

Are there more than $2009$ different homomorphisms $f:S_{2009} \rightarrow S_{2009}$ with $(1,2,3)$ in the kernel?

Prime factorization: $2009 = 7^2*41$

Tips and/or answers are welcome, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the kernel contains $(1\;2)$, it also contains every conjugate of it, that is every transposition, hence also every product of transpositions, i.e. all of $S_{2009}$. *Remark:* Here, $2009$ can be replaced by any $n\ge 2$.

If the kernel contains $(1\;2\;3)$ it also contains every 3-cycle and products therof, including $(1\;2\;3)(1\;2\;4)=(1\;3)(2\;4)$ and again  conjugates and products, hence all *even* permutations. So if the homomorphism is nontrivial the kernel must be $A_{2009}$, the image cyclic of order $2$. There are more than $2009\choose 2$ subgroups of order $2$ in $S_{2009}$, as there is already one for each two-cycle $(a\;b)$. Together with th etrivial homomorphism this gives us enough different homomorphisms. *Remark:* So here $2009$ can be replaced by any $n\ge 3$ (and in fact for $n=3$ there are *exactly* ${3\choose 2}=3$ subgroups of order $2$, but note that we still have the trivial homomorphism)

Answer (score 5):

Every non-trivial homomorphism of $S_n$ ($n>4$) has the kernel $A_n$, so $ (1,2)$ is not in the kernel.

Comment: I see, why exactly does it have the kernel $A_n$?

Comment: @ Roman Thommassen: Since $S_n$ has not others normal subgroups.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** What are the normal subgroups of $S_{2009}$?